# Count Characters a-z in range

Tags: excel, vba

How to count characters a-z in range of cells in Excel by developing a VBA. For example I have a list of names in range (A1:A10) and I need to count a,b, c, ...., and z in all range?

I have tried with loop to Chr(64 + i) and InStr but I got only which character used and not used , not the total number of letter.

- I need to find the number of occurrences of each character, for example a = 20, B= 12 and thus.
- The result range does not a matter, we can put it in Range B1:C26

Comment: Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54701816/edit) to include the code?

Comment: Do you want total number of each character or total number of characters?

Comment: You need the number of occurrences of each character? Where will you put the result? In Range B1:C26 or...?

Comment: You may try looping through all cells in the range (as the range is quite small) and also the characters through in the cell and check each characters in the  cell using `Mid` and `Asc` function to increment a counter. Using regex may be another option

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Yes I need to find the number of occurrences of each character, for example a = 20, B= 12 and thus. The result range does not a matter, we can put it in Range B1:C26

Answer (score -3, accepted):

## Range Characters Count

### The Code

```
Sub RangeCharactersCount()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet1"   ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cSrc As String = "A1:A10"     ' Source Column Range
    Const cTgt As String = "B1"         ' Target First Cell Range
    Const c1 As Long = 65               ' First Character Code ("A")
    Const c2 As Long = 90               ' Last Character Code  ("Z")

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Array Element Counter, Character Counter
    Dim strB As String    ' Concat String
    Dim LenT As Long      ' Current Length

    ' Copy Source Column Range to Source Array.
    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cSrc)
    ' Loop through elements of Source Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        ' Concatenate Concat String and current element of Source Array.
        strB = strB & vntS(i, 1)
    Next

    ' Resize Target Array to number of characters rows and 2 columns.
    ReDim vntT(1 To c2 - c1 + 1, 1 To 2)

    ' Loop through Characters.
    For i = c1 To c2
        ' Write length of Concat String to Current Length.
        LenT = Len(strB)
        ' Replace all occurrences of current letter with empty string ("").
        strB = Replace(strB, Chr(i), "", , , vbTextCompare)
        ' Write current letter to 1st column of Target Array.
        vntT(i - c1 + 1, 1) = Chr(i)
        ' Write number of occurrences (the difference between Current Length
        ' and the length of Concat String) of current letter to 2nd column of
        ' Target Array.
        vntT(i - c1 + 1, 2) = LenT - Len(strB)
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cTgt)
        ' Clear contents of Target Range (from Target First Cell Range to
        ' last cell of 2nd column).
        .Resize(.Parent.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, 2).ClearContents
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
    End With

End Sub
```